# In Bootstrap3, on button click make one div display and another div hide

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have two divs. On button click, I need the first div (topNOnav) to disappear and be replaced by the second div (topnav). Right now I have it so the second div appears on button click, but I can't get the first div to simultaneously disappear. The first div is just some text with a button and the second div is the navigation bar of our website.

HTML:

```
<div id="topNOnav" style="background-color:#0568ae" class="collapse in">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:30px">
                <img src="../../images/NewNav/nav1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div><!--end col-xs-3-->
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:center;font-family:OmnesATTIIMedium;color:white;font-size:18px;margin-top:2%">
                Take yourself to the next level!<br><i>1,000 courses to take you there.</i>
            </div><!--end col-xs-6-->
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top:2%">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#topnav" data-toggle="collapse in">Browse Courses</button>
            </div><!--end col-xs-3-->
        </div><!--end row-->
    </div><!--end container-->
  </div><!--end topNOnav-->


  <div id="topnav" class="collapse">
       <cfinclude template="../../Navigation/Responsive/NDHeader.cfm"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Post the JS you are using.

Comment: Please post what javascript you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data-parent` attribute and wrap the divs in a `panel`..

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="panel">
      <div id="topNOnav" style="background-color:#0568ae" class="collapse in">
        ...
      </div>
      <div id="topnav" class="collapse">
        ...
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/8eo6tQF0TB

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Be sure to add jquery to your project.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topNOnav").show();
  $("#topnav").hide();  
});

$("#some_button_id").click(function(){
  $("#topNOnav").hide();
  $("#topnav").show(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topNOnav" style="background-color:#0568ae" class="collapse in">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left:30px">
                <img src="../../images/NewNav/nav1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div><!--end col-xs-3-->
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:center;font-family:OmnesATTIIMedium;color:white;font-size:18px;margin-top:2%">
                Take yourself to the next level!<br><i>1,000 courses to take you there.</i>
            </div><!--end col-xs-6-->
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top:2%">
                <button id="some_button_id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#topnav" data-toggle="collapse in">Browse Courses</button>
            </div><!--end col-xs-3-->
        </div><!--end row-->
    </div><!--end container-->
  </div><!--end topNOnav-->


  <div id="topnav" class="collapse" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"> 
       <cfinclude template="../../Navigation/Responsive/NDHeader.cfm"/>
  </div>
```